# Laravel 5.5 Eloquent - Article::find returning null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two files,

`CommentTransformer`

And

`ImageTransformer`

In the first file, `CommentTransformer`, I can retrieve which Article it belongs to by doing this:

`$article = Article::find($comment->article_id);`

I'm doing the **same exact thing** in my ImageTransformer, but it returns `null`. Even if instead of using `Article::find($image->article_id)` I use `Article::find(1)` I still get a null result!

Here's the full code:

```
namespace App\Transformers;

use App\Article;
use App\User;
use App\Image;
use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;

class ImageTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
/**
 * A Fractal transformer.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function transform(Image $image)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($image->user_id);
    $article = Article::find($image->article_id);
   // $userArticle = User::find($article->user_id);
    return [
        'id'                 => (int) $image->id,
        'original_filename'  => $image->original_filename,
        'filename'           => $image->filename,
        'size'               => (int) $image->size,
        'path'               => url('/') . "/" . $image->path . '/' . $image->filename,
        'posted_by_username' => $user->name,
        'article'            => $article //if I call $article->id it returns "Trying to get property of non-object" as it is, it returns null
    ];
}
}
```

This is the response:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "original_filename": "ptd.jpg",
        "filename": "f11bbe288649e76ec3b694890160abf930601aed.jpeg",
        "size": 103297,
        "path": "http:\/\/192.168.1.85:1299\/uploads\/f11bbe288649e76ec3b694890160abf930601aed.jpeg",
        "posted_by_username": "josh beck",
        "article": null
    }
   ]
 }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Why, oh, **why** is it returning null, when I'm 100% sure there's an article with id of 1. Like I mentioned many times, even if I replace it with `$article = Article::find(1)` I get null on ImageTransformer, but **not** on CommentTransformer. Is that a good enough question? @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro

Comment: I am not able to understand your code, sorry. I am pretty sure that the line $article = Article::find(1) does not returns null. So the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Without your table structure it's hard to understand what is going wrong.
Currently it seems there is no article with `id` of `1` neither `$image->article_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that this one returns `null` because `findOrFail()` would throw an 
exception:

```
$article = Article::find($image->article_id);
```

If this returns `null`, it means there is no Article with the specified ID. You can check ID with `dd($image->article_id);`

Also, you can just load the data by using `load()` method:

```
$image->load(['user', 'article']);
```

Comment: 100% sure there's an article with the id of 1. It works on `CommentTransformer` by calling the article with the ID of 1. Edit: Also, if I replace it with `Article::find(1)` it works on `CommentTransformer` but not on `ImageTransformer` and it's really puzzling to me. A question though, how would I use the `$image->load(['user', 'article'])`? How can I load the info of those?

Comment: It's impossible for `Article::find(1)` to work in one class and to not work in another one. If you're using same `use App\Article;` in both classes, it should work. If it still doesn't work, the issue is not related to the code and you may want to check caching or something.

Comment: Ok, this is weird. `php artisan cache:clear` made it work?

Comment: @Rosenberg glad my comment was helpful. )